# speed up finite difference model

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

I have a complex finite difference model which is written in python using the same general structure as the below example code. It has two for loops one for each iteration and then within each iteration a loop for each position along the x array. Currently the code takes two long to run (probably due to the for loops). Is there a simple technique to use numpy to remove the second for loop?

Below is a simple example of the general structure I have used.

```
import numpy as np

def f(x,dt, i):
   xn = (x[i-1]-x[i+1])/dt # a simple finite difference function
   return xn

x = np.linspace(1,10,10) #create initial conditions with x[0] and x[-1] boundaries
dt = 10 #time step
iterations = 100 # number of iterations

for j in range(iterations):
    for i in range(1,9): #length of x minus the boundaries
        x[i] = f(x, dt, i) #return new value for x[i]
```

Does anyone have any ideas or comments on how I could make this more efficient?

Thanks,

Robin

Comment: Unfortunately, the body of the inner `for` loop has some nasty dependencies introduced by the structure of the function `f`. It is not parallelizable.

Comment: Why are you incrimenting "i" as soon as your inner loop starts? That just seems wholly un-necesarry when you could just have Python return a range that *starts* at 1. Also, why use a first-order central differencing method when there are other, more stable numerical techniques?

Comment: How would you structure the function to make it parallizable? That is a good call about starting the range from 1 and removing the i = i+1.

Comment: If you want to compute derivative approximations via difference quotients, then the central difference formula is `(x[1,:]-x[:-1])/(2*dt)`. You might want to use the forward and backward differentiation formulas of error order 2 `(-3*x[0]+4*x[1]-x[2])/(2*dt)` and `(3*x[-1]-4*x[-2]+x[-3])/(2*dt)` for the first and last derivative approximations.

Comment: Or did you want to solve `x'(t)=x(t)`? Then the difference formula using the central difference quotient as derivative approximation is `x[i+1]=x[i-1]+2*dt*x[i]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, this little change to the structure improves efficiency by roughly 15%. I would not be surprised if this code can be further optimized but that will most likely be algorithmic inside the function, i.e. some way to simplify the array element operation. Using a generator may likely help, too.

```
import numpy as np
import time

time0 = time.time()


def fd(x, dt, n):  # x is an array, n is the order of central diff
    for i in range(len(x)-(n+1)):
        x[i+1] = (x[i]-x[i+2])/dt # a simple finite difference function
    return x


x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)  # create initial conditions with x[0] and x[-1] boundaries
dt = 10 # time step
iterations = 1000000 # number of iterations

for __ in range(iterations):
        x = fd(x, dt, 1)
print(x)

print('time elapsed: ', time.time() - time0)
```